# box2d compilation troubles on debian jessie (8.0) with cmake

Tags: box2d

I want to compile box2d on debian jessie (8.0) with cmake.
I followed every step from the Readme.txt and Building.txt files but it doesn't compile.

```
$git clone https://github.com/erincatto/Box2D.git
```

Then I did exactly what the Building.txt tells me:

```
$cd Box2D/Build
cmake -DBOX2D_INSTALL=ON -DBOX2D_BUILD_SHARED=ON ..
make
make install
```

Now here is what i get:

```
[...]
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- Found OpenGL: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGL.so  
You have called ADD_LIBRARY for library glfw without any source files. This typically indicates a problem with your CMakeLists.txt file
-- Configuring done
CMake Error at Testbed/CMakeLists.txt:84 (add_executable):
  Cannot find source file:

    Framework/imgui.h

  Tried extensions .c .C .c++ .cc .cpp .cxx .m .M .mm .h .hh .h++ .hm .hpp
  .hxx .in .txx


CMake Error: Cannot determine link language for target "glfw".
CMake Error: CMake can not determine linker language for target: glfw
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /home/stuv/mywork/programming/c/lib/Box2D/Box2D/Build
```

I hope someone here can help me out.

Comment: I've moved the pastebin to the question. Try to include all information in the question.